# Processing - image in while loop printed only at the last state

Tags: image, while-loop, processing, shapes, stroke

I'm trying to change the color of a circle stroke by varying a RGB channel from 255 to 0 value after having released a key. In the example, press key '1'.
My issue is that the circle is printed only at the end of the while loop, and I can't see the color transition from 255 to 0. I only see the last state.
Here is the code :

```java
int RColor = 255;
int strokeWeight;
PGraphics pg;

void setup() {
  size(640, 640);
  smooth(10);
  strokeWeight = 2;
  pg = createGraphics(width, height);
  background(0);
}

void draw() {

}

void keyReleased() {
  if (key == '1') {
    while(RColor > 0) {
      drawCircle(RColor);
      RColor -= 1;
      println(RColor);
    }
  } 
}

void drawCircle(int RColor) {
    pg.beginDraw();
    pg.background(0);
    pg.noFill();
    pg.strokeWeight(strokeWeight);
    pg.stroke(RColor, 5, 224);
    pg.ellipse(56, 46, 55, 55);
    pg.endDraw();

    image(pg, 0, 0);
}
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that nothing will be drawn to the screen until the **end** of the `keyReleased()` function. All of your draw calls are to an **off-screen image**, which is then drawn to the screen at the **end** of `keyReleased()`. This is called **double-buffering**, and it's how all of the functions in Processing work.

If you want to draw individual frames of the circle, then you have to do that by splitting them up into **multiple calls to the `draw()` function**. It might look something like this:

```java
int RColor = 255;
int strokeWeight;
PGraphics pg;
boolean drawing = false;

void setup() {
  size(640, 640);
  smooth(10);
  strokeWeight = 2;
  pg = createGraphics(width, height);
  background(0);
}

void draw() {
  if (drawing && RColor > 0) {
    drawCircle(RColor);
    RColor -= 1;
    println(RColor);
  }
}

void keyReleased() {
  if (key == '1') {
    drawing = true;
  }
}

void drawCircle(int RColor) {
  pg.beginDraw();
  pg.background(0);
  pg.noFill();
  pg.strokeWeight(strokeWeight);
  pg.stroke(RColor, 5, 224);
  pg.ellipse(56, 46, 55, 55);
  pg.endDraw();

  image(pg, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm  new in processing. I've already tried the code what you wrote. What it was missing to me is the bool var used in keyReleased() to allow or not the drawing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to re think the way you structured this. `draw()` is already an infinite loop, and it only renders the image to be displayed at the end of each cycle. So the `while` will hold execution until RColor is 0, then `draw()` can render the image and show it to you. Get rid of the `while` loop and use a boolean as a flag to control stuff in draw, some thing like this:

```java
int RColor = 255;
int strokeWeight;
PGraphics pg;
boolean change = false;

void setup() {
  size(640, 640);
  smooth(10);
  strokeWeight = 2;
  pg = createGraphics(width, height);
  background(0);
}

void draw() {
 if(change && RColor >0){
     RColor -= 1;
     }else if (RColor ==0 && change){
          println("done!");
          change = false;
         }

 drawCircle(RColor);
}

void keyReleased() {
  if (key == '1') {
      change = true;
  } 
}

void drawCircle(int RColor) {
    pg.beginDraw();
    pg.background(0);
    pg.noFill();
    pg.strokeWeight(strokeWeight);
    pg.stroke(RColor, 5, 224);
    pg.ellipse(56, 46, 55, 55);
    pg.endDraw();

    image(pg, 0, 0);
}
```

related article:

https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/8085/i-display-images-in-sequence-but-i-see-only-the-last-one-why

Comment: Thank you, this is the boolean var what was missing to me. I'll keep your link, it is interresting.